# Heroku Deployement H12 issue

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, dialogflow-es, chatbot

When I am deploying using Heroku Git I keep getting 503 service unavailable. 
Please see the picture for more specification : [servistate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir48A.png)

When I check my logs ([my logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViPun.png)) it says the following message :

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/api/df_event_query"
 host=whispering-ocean-93716.herokuapp.com request_id=ec1659db-4c2c-4bc2-a3e0-95830655f055
 fwd="178.16.160.122" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Everything was working fine. I can't seem to find the error.

Here is my package.json as well (everything is up to date):

```
{
  "name": "reactbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "chatbot",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "13.9.0",
    "npm": "6.13.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "backend": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "chloe",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dialogflow": "^1.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you have an ideas for what I am doing wrong :(

Comment: plese share your index.js

Answer (score 0):

The build was successful, yet the node environment could not run your code. 
From what I can see there is some bug inside your code, this is not a Heroku error.

If it worked locally but not on Heroku, you should check the settings inside the method that invokes the POST request for the "/api/df_event_query"- endpoint.
Check if you have replaced all the localhost servers first.